# How to compare two array's value and if both are equal or not return diff. button for that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm rendering a Flatlist and in that I want to display a button based on if the ID of button is in my cart. How can I do so....

this is my code for button:

```
addBtn = (id) => {

        try{
            let productAdded = this.state.addedToCart;
            return productAdded.map((pid) => {
                if (pid == id) {
                    // console.log(pid);
                    // console.log("-----------");
                    console.log(id + " is added into cart");
                    return(
                        <Button
                            key={id}
                            style={{ 
                                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                borderWidth: 2,
                                borderColor: '#2e6153',
                                borderStyle: 'solid',
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text style={{color: '#2e6153',}}>Added</Text>
                        </Button>
                    );
                } else {
                    console.log("not added to cart");
                    return(
                        <Button
                            key={id}
                            onPress={() => {
                                this.saveCart(id);
                            }} 
                            style={{ 
                                backgroundColor: '#2e6153',
                                borderWidth: 2,
                                borderColor: '#2e6153',
                                borderStyle: 'solid',
                                width: 80,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text>Add</Text>
                        </Button>
                    );
                }
            });
        }catch(errors){
            console.log(errors);
        }

    }
```

where id of "addBtn = (id)" is coming from renderItem of FlatList.

and this.state.addedToCart is array of my items which are in my cart.
currently I added two items in cart so this.state.addedToCart = ["1015", "1016"]

and Output is:
[Here is the image of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxT3t.jpg)

I want to render it only once but buttons are rendering as many times as my cart size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there a problem:

```
return productAdded.map((pid) => {
```

just remove it and change if statement to:

```
if (productAdded.includes(id)) {
```

so it will return only one button